# Python File Managment

Tags: python

I have files being put into a folder. Each day I would like to take those files and move them into a folder with that days date as the folder name. I've been able to create the folder using the current date

```
import shutil, os
import time

date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
parent_dir = "C:\dfolder"
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, date)
os.mkdir(path)
```

This was successful creating the folder. My problem is the part of the code that will find that newly created folder each day and move the files into it. I have been able to use `shutil.move` to move the files into the folder but I have to specify the name of the destination. Is there a way to automate this each day? Maybe by having it put the files for that day into the most recently created folder or something of the sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: It makes a new folder for tomorrow and renames today's folder:

```py
import shutil, os
import time

date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
parent_dir = "C:\dfolder"
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, date)
os.rename("New folder", path) // Renames today's folder to it's proper name
os.mkdir("New folder") // Makes the new folder for tomorrow
```

This is better than checking the dates of folders being made. It just does it for you for even more automation.

Using the `os.rename` is working, however it is also moving my file.

```
import shutil, os
import time

date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
parent_dir = "C:\wfolder"


os.rename (parent_dir , date)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I hadn't thought about that approach. I have images being saved from multiple vision systems. The vision system creates a folder for these. If I were to rename this folder each day I believe I could accomplish my end goal. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. It is always good to think about different ways of doing things. Also, if this solves your question, consider marking it as correct.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem a while back. If this folder is not used for anything else the best solution is to keep a list of current files in the folder. The folder can be checked with `os.listdir()`. Then you can compare the two list and take the difference which leaves you with the most newly add file. The result of `os.listdir()` becomes your new baseline. I will try to find the exact code I used and place it here.

**Code:**

```
old_list= os.listdir(your_path)

## Your function for creating folder here ##

new_list= os.listdir(your_path)
dl = []
for item in new_list:
  if item not in old_list:
    dl.append(item)
    
dl # is the list of all new files in the directory #
```

Comment: I'll explore this avenue as well, thank you. i'd be interested in the seeing the code if you happen to run across it. thank you

Comment: This is the code I used. One last thing that helped me immensely. If you are not using `pathlib` for managing directories  it might be worth  looking at. Disclaimer: I have nothing to do with `pathlib` I just use it.

Comment: If you are defining the old list the same way as the new list, and looping over them, you are just duplicating items. This code will not work.

Comment: It does work, I actively use it in one of my file automation systems. The function in between the new list and old list changes the contents of the directory; `dl` is a list of the changed files.